# How to name files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to be ignored without warnings?

Tags: debian, aptitude, repository

```
N: Ignoring file 'cloudera.list_' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'opera.list_' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
...
N: Ignoring file 'tor.list_' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

How to properly "comment out" files there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cat >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/98ignore_extensions << \EOF
# Follow the pattern to add more extensions to ignore.
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.gz$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.save$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.distUpgrade$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.list_$";
EOF
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser. Although this will answer the question, would you mind to explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 4):

I just move the files to `../sources.list.disabled/`.

Comment: But `mv tor.list{_,}` looks nicer than `mv ../source.list{.disabled,}/tor.list`

Answer (score 3):

[kubuntu 18.04]

I could not work out why the suffixes `.distUpgrade` and `.save` were ignored when there did not appear to be anything that explicitly sets this.

Then I discovered `apt-config dump | grep -i ignore` has entries for these and others:

```
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently "";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "~$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.disabled$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.bak$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.dpkg-[a-z]+$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.ucf-[a-z]+$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.save$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.orig$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.distUpgrade$";
```

I just renamed my dodgy one to be of of those extensions.  (I chose `.orig`)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/sources.list.5.en.html)

**TLDR**
Files need to have the following

**extension:**
 - `.list`
 - `.sources`

**filename:**
  - contain letters (a-z and A-Z)
  - digits (0-9)
  - underscore (_)
  - hyphen (-)
  - period (.)

[SOURCES.LIST.D](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/sources.list.5.en.html)
The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add sources.list entries in separate files. Two different file formats are allowed as described in the next two sections. Filenames need to have either the extension .list or .sources depending on the contained format. The filenames may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_), hyphen (-) and period (.) characters. Otherwise APT will print a notice that it has ignored a file, unless that file matches a pattern in the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in which case it will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to larsks [answer](https://superuser.com/a/235245/521602): I use the same kind of directory hierarchy as Apache (`/etc/apache2`) or Fontconfig (`/etc/fonts`).

The idea is to have two directories:

- `something.avail` for all your files.
- `something.d` that contains symlinks to the files you actually use.

Code speaks better than words, so here it comes.

```
cd /etc/apt
mv sources.list.d sources.list.avail
mkdir sources.list.d
cd sources.list.d
# Now you can symlink the files you want to use
ln -s ../sources.list.avail/liquorix.list
ln -s ../sources.list.avail/goodvibes.list
...
```